# Extract different hashtags "#" from a text stored in a Dataframe with the R language

Tags: r, twitter, tweets, tidytext

I have a data frame with some tweets and i want to extract the hashtags from the tweets using the unnest_tokens() function of tidytext package , creating a tokenized data frame with one row per hashtag.

My data only have 3 columns:

1. Fecha: that is a the dates od the tweets in a POSIXct variable type.
2. Usuario: that is the id user of the tweets in a Numeric varible  type.
3. Texto: that is the text the tweeets in a character variable type.

[image]

```
otros_numerales_numeral_petro  <- Numeral_Petro_sin_emojis %>% 
unnest_tokens(output = "hashtag", input = "Texto", token = "tweets") %>%
filter(str_starts(hashtag, "#"))
```

But, when i run the code i got this error:

> Error:
> ! Support for `token = "tweets"` was deprecated in tidytext
> 0.4.0 and is now defunct.

Can someone help me to fix this, please.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/issues/232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the `token = "tweets"` option [was deprecated](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/blob/main/NEWS.md#tidytext-040) at the end of last year because of changes in upstream dependencies. It sounds you don't want to tokenize the text really, but rather extract all the hashtags. I would do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rtweet)
bunny_tweets <- 
  search_tweets("#rabbits", n = 20, include_rts = FALSE) %>%
  filter(!possibly_sensitive, lang == "en")

bunny_tweets %>%
  mutate(hashtags = str_extract_all(full_text, "#\\S+")) %>%
  unnest(hashtags) %>%
  select(id, hashtags, full_text)
#> # A tibble: 142 × 3
#>         id hashtags          full_text                                          
#>      <dbl> <chr>             <chr>                                              
#>  1 1.64e18 #Animate          "This awesome comic deserves more attention!\n \n#…
#>  2 1.64e18 #Doujinshi        "This awesome comic deserves more attention!\n \n#…
#>  3 1.64e18 #rabbits          "This awesome comic deserves more attention!\n \n#…
#>  4 1.64e18 #april            "New baby bunny spotted! #april #rabbits\nBlack ba…
#>  5 1.64e18 #rabbits          "New baby bunny spotted! #april #rabbits\nBlack ba…
#>  6 1.64e18 #LFDIE            "Trust me! You'll get addicted to this story!\n \n…
#>  7 1.64e18 #rabbits          "Trust me! You'll get addicted to this story!\n \n…
#>  8 1.64e18 #huacheng         "Trust me! You'll get addicted to this story!\n \n…
#>  9 1.64e18 #digitalanimation "I've been completely addicted to ONEPIECE and Mar…
#> 10 1.64e18 #rabbits          "I've been completely addicted to ONEPIECE and Mar…
#> # … with 132 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>